# Modify the locale collation order in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sorting, unicode

The collation order is what determines the order strings are sorted in for a given locale. It comes in two layers, the root order which determines that all variants of A is treated as a (Á À Ä Ã ...), and the locale order which adds to the root. For example in Swedish, Å and Ä which normally sorts under A are instead placed as new letters after Z.

I want a way to modify the active locale's collation order in Windows 10. For example, running in Spanish, I want to be able to modify the [Spanish collation order](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/collation/es.xml) and for example add "ny" as a valid variant to "ñ". `&N<ñ<<<Ñ<<<ny<<<Ny<<<NY` This would make any "ny" be treated as if it was written as "ñ" when sorting, as an example.

This modification should affect all software that reads the collation order from Windows, such as Windows Explorer, Microsoft Excel, Windows Media Player.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @music2myear nothing, I don't know where to start

Comment: For reference. This question was [discussed in Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/iehg9m/your_question_is_stupid/g2lknkb/).